# How do I compare a datetime field to a time expressed in minutes using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select a row only if it is younger than a set time, in this case 5 minutes: I'm not sure how to tell MySQL that `5` is minutes, and not an int. As such, I can't do this:

SELECT data from dataTable WHERE `data.createdAt < 5`

createdAt is a datetime field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job:

```
SELECT data FROM dataTable 
            WHERE data.createdAt > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Pekka, many thanks. There is something that I don't understand: why is the operator reversed? I would expect to use "<" instead of ">" since I am looking for something less than 5 minutes. Why is this?

Comment: @Mel the way it is now, it says "give me all records whose date is greater than five minutes ago". It would catch future dates as well but that shouldn't be an issue here